# Why am I getting float instead of integer pixel values in OpenGL using GL_R32I renderbuffer format?

Tags: c++, opengl, pixel

Using OpenGL 4.5 on an nVidia gpu.  I need to generate an image with 32 bit integer pixels, but am getting float values instead.

I'm using a renderbuffer created with internal format GL_R32I.  This is documented as an unnormalized integer format; OGL runtime reports that it is fully supported for writing and reading.

OpenGL reports the read buffer internal format as GL_RED_INTEGER and pixel type as GL_INT.  I can put different integer values in the renderbuffer by casting an int to float in glClearColor(), and glReadPixels() returns those bit patterns intact.

For testing I am initializing the buffer to -1.  The frag shader outputs a single integer per triangle, however the output image contains the equivalent float values.

Here is the code:

```
/* render a triangle index image 
*  vertex coords on pixel grid
*  origin upper left
*  pixel value is triangle id
*/

static const char* index_vs_text =
"#version 450\n"
"uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec2 vPos;\n"
"layout(location = 1) in int Tdx;\n"
"out flat int tid;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, -1.0, 1.0);\n"
"    tid = Tdx;\n"
"}\n";

static const char* index_fs_text =
"#version 450\n"
"layout(origin_upper_left) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;\n"
"in flat int tid;\n"
"out unsigned int color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   color = tid;\n"
"}\n";

bool GLops::tridx_image(
    int width,
    int height,
    int* pixels,    // result array
    int ntris,      // number of triangles
    int* pvtids,    // vertex indices, 3 per tri
    int nverts,     // number of vertices
    float* verts    // 2D vertex coordinates
) {
    if (window == 0)
        return false;

    /* convert input to canonical arrays that can be
       rendered with glDrawArrays:
    * vpos  3 {x, y} coords per triangle (y inverted)
    * vtid  triangle id 3 times per tri
    */
    int nv = 3 * ntris,
        nc = 2 * nv;
    vector<float> vvpos(nc);
    vector<int> vvtid(nv);
    float* vpos = vvpos.data(),
        * pos = vpos;
    int* vtid = vvtid.data(),
       * pid = vtid,
       * pdx = pvtids;
    for (int itri = 0; itri < ntris; itri++, pid += 3, pdx += 3 ) {
        pid[0] = pid[1] = pid[2] = itri;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, pos += 2) {
            int j = 2 * pdx[i];
            pos[0] = verts[j++];
            pos[1] = verts[j];
        }
    }

    /* model/view/projection matrix */
    glm::mat4 mvp = glm::ortho(
        0.f, float(width),
        0.f, float(height),
        0.5f, 1.5f
    );

    GLuint vao, fbo, rbo,
        vertex_buffer, tid_buffer,
        vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
    GLint mvp_loc, vpos_loc, tid_loc;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);

    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &index_vs_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    if (compile_error(vertex_shader, "tridx vs"))
        return false;

    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &index_fs_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
    if(compile_error(fragment_shader, "tridx fs"))
        return false;

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "fragcolor");
    glLinkProgram(program);
    if (program_error(program, "tridx"))
        return false;

    mvp_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    vpos_loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
    tid_loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "Tdx");

    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&mvp);

    if (ogl_error("tridx link"))
        return false;

    if (pixels == 0)
        return false;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nv * 2 * sizeof(float), vpos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_loc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &tid_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tid_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nv * sizeof(int), vtid, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(tid_loc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(tid_loc, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    GLenum RBfmt = GL_R32I;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        RBfmt,
        width,
        height
    );
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(
        GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        rbo
    );

    if (ogl_error("tridx buffers"))
        return false;

    /* check validity of renderbuffer format */
    GLint RBparms[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };
    GLenum supp_full = GL_FULL_SUPPORT,
        supp_caveat = GL_CAVEAT_SUPPORT,
        supp_none = GL_NONE;
    glGetInternalformativ(
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        RBfmt,
        GL_INTERNALFORMAT_SUPPORTED,
        4,
        RBparms
    );
    glGetInternalformativ(
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        RBfmt,
        GL_COLOR_RENDERABLE,
        3,
        RBparms + 1
    );
    glGetInternalformativ(
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        RBfmt,
        GL_FRAMEBUFFER_RENDERABLE,
        2,
        RBparms + 2
    );
    glGetInternalformativ(
        GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        RBfmt,
        GL_READ_PIXELS,
        1,
        RBparms + 3
    );

    GLenum fbs = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fbs != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        return false;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    int bg = -1;
    glClearColor(*(float*)&bg, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glDrawArrays(
        GL_TRIANGLES, 0, nv
    );

    glFinish();
 
    if(ogl_error("tridx render"))
        return false;

    GLint 
        rdfmt,  // gets GL_RED or GL_RED_INTEGER
        rdtyp;  // gets GL_FLOAT or GL_UNSIGNED_INT
    glGetFramebufferParameteriv(
        GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT,
        &rdfmt  
    );
    glGetFramebufferParameteriv(
        GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE,
        &rdtyp  
    );

    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, rdfmt, rdtyp, pixels);

    if (ogl_error("tridx read"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not a showstopper for the current app, whose triangle indexes will fit comfortably in 24 bits.  However I would like to have the full 32 bit unsigned integer range available for future work.

Answer (score 0):

For `glClear` OpenGL spec says the following:

> The result of clearing integer color buffers is undefined.

The correct way to clear a signed integer color buffer is to use:

```
GLint clear_value[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1}; // needs four values even if only one is used
glClearBufferiv(GL_COLOR, 0 /*drawbuffer*/, clear_value);
// or:
glClearNamedFramebufferiv(fbo, GL_COLOR, 0 /*drawbuffer*/, clear_value);
```

Additionally, if your vertex shader expects an integer attribute, you shall use `glVertexAttribIPointer` as follows:

```
glVertexAttribIPointer(tid_loc, 1, GL_INT, 0, 0);
```

The reason that `glVertexAttribPointer` doesn't work is because it assumes that the shader expects a floating point values, thus an integer data will be either cast to a float (i.e. 42 -> 42.0) or normalized (i.e. 42 -> 42.0/0x7fffffff), neither of which is what you need.

Comment: I am specifying GL_INT in the glVertexAttribPointer call, and the corresponding shader input is declared int.

Comment: @ThomasSharpless yes, but that's the wrong function to use. Notice the capital letter `I` in the function `glVertexAttrib____I____Pointer` that's in my answer. `glVertexAttribPointer` (without the `I`) assumes that the shader expects a float. `GL_INT` then refers to the type of the values in the VAO, not the type of the shader input.

Comment: Many thanks for illuminating this dark corner of OpenGL.  I could never have found the right incantations by studying the documentation.  How did you do it?

Comment: Read the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf). This is what I do.